# pyspark getting weeknumber of month

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am stuckup with getting weeknumber from month in pyspark from a datafrme column , For Examples consider my dataframe as

```
WeekID,DateField,WeekNUM
1,01/JAN/2017
2,15/Feb/2017
```

My Output should be as below

```
WeekIDm,DateField,MOF
1,01/JAN/2017,1
2,15/FEB/2017,2
```

I tried with striftime and other date functions I was unable to do.

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 8):

You can combine `to_date` and `date_format`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, date_format

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "01/JAN/2017"), (2, "15/FEB/2017")], ("id", "date"))

df.withColumn("week", date_format(to_date("date", "dd/MMM/yyyy"), "W")).show()
+---+-----------+----+
| id|       date|week|
+---+-----------+----+
|  1|01/JAN/2017|   1|
|  2|15/FEB/2017|   3|
+---+-----------+----+
```

If you want week-of-year please replace format with `w`:

```
date_format(to_date("date", "dd/MMM/yyyy"), "w")
```

Answer (score 2):

Since spark 3.0 flag `w` has been deprecated.
So, Simply you can use PySpark inbuilt function `weekofyear` as follows -

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as funcs

(df
 .withColumn(
    'week_of_year', 
    funcs.weekofyear(funcs.col('date_announced'))).select('date_announced', 'week_of_year')
).show(5)

+-------------------+------------+
|     date_announced|week_of_year|
+-------------------+------------+
|2020-01-30 00:00:00|           5|
|2020-02-02 00:00:00|           5|
|2020-02-03 00:00:00|           6|
|2020-03-02 00:00:00|          10|
|2020-03-02 00:00:00|          10|
+-------------------+------------+
```