# Adding date & calendar week column in py spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using spark 2.4.5. I want to add two new columns, date & calendar week, in my pyspark data frame df.
So I tried the following code:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
df.withColumn('timestamp', F.lit('2020-05-01'))
df.show()
```

But I'm getting error message: `AssertionError: col should be Column`

Can you explain how to add date column & calendar week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed the `lit` function in your code.
Here's what you were looking for:

```
df = df.withColumn("date", lit('2020-05-01'))
```

This is your answer if you want to **hardcode** the date and week. If you want to programmatically derive the current timestamp, I'd recommend using a UDF.

Answer (score 1):

I see two questions here: First, how to cast a string to a date. Second, how to get the week of the year from a date.

#### Cast string to date

You can either simply use `cast("date")` or the more specific `F.to_date`.

```py
df = df.withColumn("date", F.to_date("timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

#### Extract week of year

Using format date allows you to format a date column to any desired format. `w` is the week of the year. `W` would be the week of the month.

```py
df = df.withColumn("week_of_year", F.date_format("date", "w"))
```

Related Question: [pyspark getting weeknumber of month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336137/pyspark-getting-weeknumber-of-month)